# Can I make Firefox return to a specific spot on the page when using "back"?

Tags: firefox

Can I make Firefox return to a specific spot on the page when using "back"? Internet Explorer seems to do this.

Comment: Firefox (currently using 4.0.1) does this for me.  Does it fail for you only on some pages, or on all pages?  I just tried a Wikipedia article to be sure, and yes, it does return to the spot I was reading.  If it is a long page it may need to load for a while before it seeks to the place.

Comment: If it is a long page it may need to load for a while before it seeks to the place - agreed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. create new Firefox profile, which will be with default settings;
2. Run Firefox in [Safe Mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_Mode) and see.

If option 2 works then you have issues with yours add-ons.

Comment: Option 2 did work ok (and faster!) I'll deactivate add-ons 1 at a time to prove, and report results back here. thanx

Comment: I decided to deactivate addons in Alpha order. Didn't take long, it was "APTURE" addon..Solved.